# Laravel Passport Request Token Don't response

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

[image] I request passport token using Requesting Tokens but it is loading in postman nothing response.

This is my source code
$http = new Client;

```
    $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '3',
            'client_secret' => 'AMZucpstZeT1RvZwBl96FNIqzDToOy32yFQglzfy',
            'username' => 'dtowne@example.org',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);
```

if I change http://localhost:8000 to your-app.com data response null

Comment: try adding headers param using basic authentication with username and password credentials. using [RFC 7617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617)